# New onclick return when clicking on button

Tags: html, model-view-controller, onclick, return

The existing code is below, but I'd like to add a new onclick that returns a Pop-up box asking the user if they are sure they want to delete the profile. Can't figure it out though..

Existing Code:

```
 @if(mode == "Edit"){
        <div class="Delete"><a class="btn btn-danger" href ="@Url.Action("Delete", "GPS", new { Id = Model.provider.Company.Id.Value, oem = Model.provider.Id})">Delete Profile</a></div>  
        }
```

I tried adding this, but it wasn't cooperating.

```
 new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the profile?')"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your js it should be like this :

```
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the profile?')){
   // code to execute if ok is pressed
   // in your case it could be a redirection to the url you need
} else {
   // code if canceled is pressed, may not be used
}
```

The thing to know is that it works cause confirm will return true if ok and false if cancel.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp